# HTML Embed object has a grey background. Can it be transparent?

Tags: html, css, firefox, embed, browser-plugin

I'm using Firefox with an opensource plugin to playback video. The video is scaled "as good as possible" to fit the available space defined in the width and height of the embed object. But sometimes there is a little grey border on the right and/or bottom.

It seems this isn't the bgcolor of my parent div as changing it has no effect at all.

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="videoHolder" style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px; width: 300px; height: 150px;">
 <embed id="player" width="300" height="150" border="0" type="application/x-gbp" x-gbp-uri="">
</div>
```

Anyone knows of a way to define an embed to be transparent? 
Setting wmode=transparent as with Flash has no effect...

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Please make a demo or provide a link to your site if it's live.

Comment: You can style the background of an `embed` tag however you want.  However the gray box you see isn't the background of the element, it's content that is being rendered on top of the background.  As you can see by adding some padding to the `embed` tag:  http://jsfiddle.net/FypSq/.

Comment: sorry, demo is not possible as the plugin only works on special Linux client with dedicated software...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general way to tell plugin elements to be transparent from the browser-side, plugins need to support that themselves in their native code.

For Flash setting the `wmode="transparent"` works, but only because Flash implements that itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "wmode" attribute and setting it's value to "transparent":

```
<div id="videoHolder" style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px; width: 300px; height: 150px;">
    <embed WMODE="transparent" id="player" width="300" height="150" border="0" type="application/x-gbp" x-gbp-uri="">
</div>
```

Comment: @Frank Can't you just paste your website's url?

Comment: sorry, demo is not possible as the plugin only works on special Linux client with dedicated software...

Comment: @Frank You can specify wmode in embed and object - try both - but these depends on how your whole embedding code looks like. If any other DOM is overlapping with your video you can adjust their z-indexes. Without actually seeing your page I won't be able to help you any further. :(

Comment: The wmode attribute is specific to flash.