# how to remove black background of audio player in html

Tags: html

I embedded an audio on my web page with `<embed>` but there is a black background behind the player.
Why does this happen and how should I remove it? Or is there any other better way to embed the audio?

```
[<embed src="../audio/introduction.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" bgcolor="" >]
```

This is how the audio player looks like:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktr1P.png

Comment: A [mcve] (in the form of a Stack Snippet) would be most appreciated.

Comment: @SinclairWong Share a snippet of the audio player working code, if possible, expected output image!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTML5 then `<audio>` tag is the best choice for you:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: It helps! Thanks a lot! I have been bothered by this for a long time. But do you know why the black background appeared?

Comment: The HTML <embed> element embeds external content at the specified point in the document. This content is provided by an external application or other source of interactive content such as a browser plug-in. Keep in mind that most modern browsers have deprecated and removed support for browser plug-ins, so relying upon <embed> is generally not wise if you want your site to be operable on the average user's browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed

Answer (score 1):

We can use HTML5 Audio tag for this purpose instead of embed

```html
 <audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: It helps! Thanks a lot! I have been bothered by this for a long time. But do you know why the black background appeared?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261216/html-embed-object-has-a-grey-background-can-it-be-transparent. Check this i think its similer to your problem

Comment: I don't really understand the explanation. Does it mean the black background is just set in their code?

Comment: <embed src="../audio/introduction.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" bgcolor="#ff0000 !important" >    Try giving an important to bgcolor

Comment: The black background remains.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was on dynamic coloured background, I did this:

```css
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel { 
    background-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.16);
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```